# Customizing the breadcrumb

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

could you help me to implement a custom breadcrumb on the order history/order details page?
The default breadcrumb is only showing `Home` instead of `Home > Order history` or `Home > Order history > Order #12345`

How can i define my breadcrumbs depending on the used component / used routing path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve customization of breadcrumbs for certain pages by using `MetaResolvers` and overriding `BreadcrumbComponent`.

MetaResolver allows you to handle meta data for specific given page type and/or page template and has an interface called `resolveBreadcrumbs()` which handles breadcrumb structure for the given page. You can observe the meta resolver for product page for example [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/product/services/product-page-meta.resolver.ts)

For the furthest on the right of the breadcrumb, say it's title (Order #12345 in your case), I've achieved by customizing the BreadcrumbComponent in my code.

**custom-breadcrumb.component.ts**

```
export class CustomBreadcrumbComponent extends BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  
  isOrderDetailPage: boolean;

  constructor(private pageLayoutService: PageLayoutService,
              private orderDetailsService: OrderDetailsService) {

  this.pageLayoutService.page$.subscribe(page => {
  this.isOrderDetailPage = page.pageId === 'order';
})

this.order$ = this.orderDetailsService.getOrderDetails();

}

ngOnInit() {
  super.ngOnInit();
 }
}
```

**custom-breadcrumb.component.html**

```
<div class="custom-breadcrumb">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
     <span *ngIf="isOrderDetailPage && order$ | async as order"> <a>{{order?.code}}</a></span>
   </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Harvey for clarifing this. I did understand the concept of the `MetaResolvers` and kinda achieved this already but wanted to use the proper way providing the information via `routingPageMetaResolver` instead of filtering all the data inside the custom-breadcrumb.component.html